# Angular Material Md-toolbar Input

Tags: input, angularjs-material

Is there a way to add md-input-container within the md-toolbar like this?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Simply add the `md-input-container` into the toolbar.

```
<md-toolbar class="myCustomClass">
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
      <label>Search for item</label> 
      <input ng-model="searchPhrase" name="searchPhrase">
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

You may need to adjust the vertical alignment if the search box sits high. You can do this by adding the following css:

```
.myCustomClass md-input-container .md-errors-spacer{
  min-height: 0px !important;
}
```

Obviously the correct way would be to create a custom class for the input in the toolbar and apply the above style so you don't end up overriding the default styles of other input tags.

Comment: Thanks I was missing the <input> part under the label. How would you create the custom class you were referring to?

Comment: @Flash - updated my answer. Just add the custom class to the `md-toolbar` tag and then make sure you update the css to make use of this inheritance.